# How to extract a username from an email address using Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using the following script to get the user's email address:

```
  function getEmail() {
  var userEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()
  Logger.log(userEmail);
  }
```

It logs something like this: username@domain.com

I'd like to extract the username (everything to the left of @) and log it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About `It logs something like this: username@domain.com`, when your showing script is run, you can see `username@domain.com` in the log. And, you want to retrieve `username` from `username@domain.com`, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```
function getEmail() {
  var userName = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail().split("@")[0];
  Logger.log(userName);
}
```

#### Reference:

- [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: Brilliant! Simple, elegant, and works perfectly. I can see that "@" designates the character for the split. What does [0] do?

Comment: @d-ron Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `What does [0] do?`, this means 1st element of the array. When `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail().split("@")` is run, the value `username@domain.com` retrieved by `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()` is converted to an array like `["username", "domain.com"]` by `split("@")`. From this array, when `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail().split("@")[0]` is run, the 1st element of `"username"` is retrieved. This value is your expected value.

Comment: VERY helpful @Tanaike. I was able to understand your explanation.